# How to emit a state change from an external event

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm new to using the Bloc pattern in Flutter, and I wish to update some widgets (i.e. state) for every bloc concerned by an external change.

For example, imagine that I have a trading application, and so I have a "Trading" component that receive some information updates.

My "Trading" component receive new information, but then how does it transmit the new information to the Bloc and so, how it emits (and update) the widget.

Any idea how I can do this? What is the correct pattern to follow ?

Comment: From where do you receive this new information?

Answer (score 0):

You need to emit the state changes (your trading data here) to your state using a **BLoC / Cubit** which will then rebuild the UI using [BlocBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Thanks, this I understand. But how can I "contact" the Bloc from my custom component. Imagine I have a class "Trading", how does it notify all the TradingBloc?

Comment: I don't quite understand exactly what do you want to do. If you want to contact the Bloc from your class you will need to use the instance of your bloc/cubit which you are using for the states. For e.g, if you have a TradingBloc and a TradingScreen, you will be having an instance of that bloc from which you can trigger the events in the Bloc which will then do the required work and emit the state, when the state will change all your UI components that are listening to the Bloc changes will be rebuilt.

Comment: My problem is more that I have a singleton class "TradingManager" that receive asynch event from a remote web site/API.  The TradingManager is then update in realtime, but can I connect it to the BLOC ? "TradingManager" is not a widget.

Notice that I have multiples BLOC that should receive the same events, because they display the sale info but in different ways.